# YouTube API v3 Error: 403 but the API key is configured and Bundle identifier is correct

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-api, google-api

I need to pull the name of a specific channels playlists from youtube.  I am using AFJSONRequestOperation to make the call.

I keep getting the error code "Expected status code in (200-299), got 403".  I have registered with google and my bundle identifier is correct.

Here is My code (I crossed out the last ten characters of my api KEY):

```
   NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=UCHvTZKuI5zQnxmbgSE-CFug&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyDHU-hMgwLf0a4vZe4pPDxqyxxxxxxxxxx"];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];


AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                     JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){
                                         NSLog(@"%@,",JSON[0][@"title"]);

                                     }failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){
                                         NSLog( @"NSError: %@", error.localizedDescription);

                                     }];

[operation start];
```

The solutions I have tried are as follows:
- Using the browser key.
- Regenerating the key.
- Triple checking the bundle identifier.
- have added the google cloud api's and the youtube analytics and the youtube data api.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
-Joel

Comment: Joel, check to see if the token is still valid. Access tokens are only valid for one hour. Check out this post: http://ikaisays.com/2013/07/19/debugging-your-google-oauth-2-0-token-when-you-get-http-401s-or-403s/

Comment: The other thing I might suggest is using the official Objective-C library, which will take care of key management for you: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

Comment: I tried to debug using the post you linked to, I keep getting either 403 Forbidden or 400 invalid call but I have triple checked the call.  I will try the objectivec-client library next.

Comment: This issue is reported internally. You can track it through public issue tracker.
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5770

Comment: How would you suggest me to proceed from here

Comment: I just removed the bundle identifier and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug - I fixed it by removing the bundle identifier from my registered app.